# How can I stop the sides of Unity windows from behaving like corners when I'm resizing with a mouse?

Tags: unity, mouse, window, resize

Sometimes, my desktop will get into a state such that when I click on a side (including bottom or top) of a window to resize it, then, *in addition* to being able to resize that edge (perpendicular to the direction of the edge itself), moving the mouse *parallel* to the side will cause the window to resize in the other direction as well.

In other words: I'm trying to resize horizontally by grabbing the right or left edge (and that works fine), but if I move my mouse vertically, the bottom of the window moves as well.

Similarly, if I grab the top or bottom edge, moving my mouse horizontally will resize the right edge.

Anyone know how to get out of that state, short of restarting?